# Is there more than one type of tapered steerer?

Tags: fork, steerer

I have a set of forks (Rock Shox XC/30/TK on a Focus Black Raider 2.0 2012) that measure 30mm at the bottom and 28.6mm at the top, (or 1 3⁄16" to 1⅛" in pre-enlightenment measurements). So they're tapered, but they're not 1½" to 1⅛" like a [standard tapered steerer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6475/tapered-head-tube).

So are they tapered or straight? I am looking for a replacement because the dampener popped out of them and I need to know what to be looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Official website says](https://www.sram.com/rockshox/products/xc-30-tk) that these are the only models available:

> 1-1/8" STKM steel, 1-1/8" aluminum (-163g), XL 1-1/8" steel, XL 1-1/8"
>   aluminum, 1.5" to 1-1/8" tapered aluminum (-123g), 1.5" aluminum
>   (-146g)

Your fork is straight, the taper at the bottom is required for interference fitted crown race. I've measured straight Suntour XCM just in case and it has same dimensions as in the the question.