# Fitting 1-1/8" straight fork in Giant Overdrive headset

Tags: headset, giant

I have a 2013 Giant Defy 3 with a broken fork.  The original steerer tube is tapered: 1-1/8" on top and 1-1/4" on the bottom.  I'm trying to figure out how to replace the fork with a more common 1-1/8" straight steerer.

The head tube measures 42mm top and 47mm bottom, and the bearings are integrated. So I'd like to find a reducer sleeve that fits inside my existing bearing and reduces it down to 1-1/8". Not sure if this exists. 
Alternatively, I guess I could buy a reducer ring that goes outside the bearing, and a new 1-1/8" bearing.

Then I have to figure out what angle of race I need.  I'm not sure how to measure that on the existing bearing.

Comment: This isn't a proper answer, because I don't know enough, but you might check out https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/6483/43557 about adapting a tapered head tube.  It appears that 1-1/4" isn't as common as 1.5", but some searching turns up a few options like https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ritchey-comp-headset-lowers-drop-in/rp-prod130226 or https://www.competitivecyclist.com/chris-king-inset-8-headset?ti=OjoxOjE6

Comment: A number of head set manufacturers have fitting tools - e.g. (not a recommendation https://blue.canecreek.com/headset-fit-finder